# How to fill out an Apps Script OAuth Client Verification form - Link to Privacy Policy

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth

In order to avoid a warning that your Apps Script code is "Unsafe" and not verified, you need to fill out an Apps Script OAuth Client Verification form.

Link to Application Form:
[OAuth Developer Verification Form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification)

I filled out the form and submitted it, but my request was not approved because I need to link my Privacy Policy to the OAuth Consent screen in the Google Cloud Console.

But I'm not sure where to find the place to enter the link to my privacy policy.

Comment: To the close voters: I don't think Stack Overflow will want this.  While it's about a "tool that developers may use," I think it's more about navigating the UI of this particular form in Google's console, which is effectively a "web application."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Access the Credentials section of the project at Google Cloud Console.

   - `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=project-id-#####`
2. Click "OAuth consent screen".
3. Input the link to "Privacy policy URL".
4. Click "Save" button.

The "Privacy policy URL" input field is outlined by a red line.

[image]